# What is the Date type in npgsql?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, date, npgsql

I am using postgreSQL database. I need to add "Date" parametres with SQL query. What do I have to write where I wrote in the code "XXX" 
Here is the source code:

```
NpgsqlCommand RupCmd = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE TABLE SET dat1=@dno,dat2=@dlidz,id_viesis=@idv,id_istaba=@idi WHERE rezervacijas_id=@id", con);
RupCmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@dno", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date, XXX, "dat1"));
RupCmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@dlidz", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date, XXX, "dat2"));
RupCmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@idv", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "id_viesis"));
RupCmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@idi", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "id_istaba"));
RupCmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "rezervacijas_id"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave it with zero, i.e.

```
RupCmd.Parameters.Add(
     new NpgsqlParameter("@dno", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date, 0, "dat1"));
```

Comment: That's weird, I always set the size to 0 whatever type it is. What's the output's error?

Comment: It works right now, maybe I accidentally changed something, but I don't know what exactly. :D Maybe some comma was missing.