# Problems with Data type in Npgsql query

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to insert a row in a PostgreSQL table with a date column. On the UI, I got a DateTimePicker where the user selectes the proper date. So far I got this:

On the UI:

```
objPresupuesto.date = this.dtpFechaPres.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

On the method who inserts the row:

```
NpgsqlCommand query = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into presupuesto(presupuesto, codigo, descripcion, fecha, cliente, proyecto, total) values(nextval('presupuesto_presupuesto_seq'), @codigo, @descripcion, @fecha, @cliente, @proyecto,  @total);Select lastval();", conn);            
...
query.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("fecha", NpgsqlDbType.Date, 0, "fecha"));
...
query.Parameters[2].Value = obj.date.toString;//without the toString it also fails
```

It throws this exception:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

The obj.date value is 2011-04-29.  tryied putting single quotes around, but It also fails.

The database column type is date.

Anyone has done this before? Any ideas?

I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498114/what-is-the-date-type-in-npgsql) searching for and aswer but it doesn't helped.
Thanks

Comment: Hmmmmmm, can you provide me a simple test case? Did you try using an NpgsqlDate object?

Comment: @FranciscoJunior I tryied with the NpgsqlDate and it works, but it's a little bit tricky, I don't know if there is a direct way to do this. thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I also think it could be more straightforward. Can you provide me with a simple console based test app so I can have a look at it? Also, if possible, please fill a bug report about that at: bugs.npgsql.org Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed is that when you are adding your parameter it is missing the "@" from the beginning where your command references the value with the "@".

Are you sure that the Parameters[2] is your "fecha" parameter?

Answer (score 1):

1. try use:

`npgsqlCommand.Parameters.Add("fecha", NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;`

For more readable code.

2. Type of `obj.date` is DateTime struct?
3. Add to connection string parameter `Convert Infinity DateTime`
   For more info check: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

query.Parameters[2].Value = CDate(obj.date)